# What is Angular 5 supporting version

Tags: ngx-uploader

What is Angular 5 supporting version of @ngx-uploader, 
I am having issue installed "npm install ngx-uploader --save",looking no data in console. 
its showing in package.json "ngx-uploader": "^6.0.1".

Answer (score 2):

you can just use Id selector and fetch file. Try it once.

Comment: @ShashikantPandit could you expand on your answer please?

Comment: Hi @CameronW. Either we can use the Id selector, that means that assign a Id in html file input div or just use the (uploadOutput)="onUploadOutput($event)" in input  div and create a function named same in .ts file,         


onUploadOutput(output: UploadOutput): void {
console.log(output)
    debugger;
    const file: File = output.file.nativeFile;
}